# Extending Minimal sufficient statistics to arbitrary dimension

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference, estimators, sufficient-statistics

I am wondering if the following reasoning is correct regarding minimal sufficiency and dimension. Given $X_1,\dots,X_n$ i.i.d. $N(\mu,1)$, we know that the sample mean $S = \bar{X}$ is a minimal sufficient statistic. Let $T := [1^T_{d-1}, \bar{X}]^T \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$ be the $d$ -dimensional vector of all ones in the first $d-1$ coordinates and $\bar{X}$ in the $d$-th coordinate.

Then $T$ is minimal sufficient because $T$ is sufficient and there exists a function $f$ such that $T=f(S)$. Since we know that $S$ is minimal, for any other sufficient statistic $Z$, there exists a function so that $S=h(Z)$. This in turn implies that $T = f(S)=f(h(Z)) = (f \circ h )(Z) $ and so $T$ is a function of any other sufficient statistic.

Comment: The above implication goes the wrong way:. $S$ is minimal since it is a function of any other sufficient statistic, incl. $T$.

Comment: @Xi'an I updated my question to clarify what I was trying to do

Comment: You still haven't addressed @Xi'an's point.

Comment: @whuber - i guess i don't understand the comment then.. I am not claiming that S is not minimal, I am using the minimality of S to show that T is also minimal. Could you please clarify what exactly it is that I'm not addressing?

Comment: The relationship between $T$ and $S$ is trivial--it's meaningless to carry a bunch of constants along with a statistic--making it unclear what you are trying to show or where you are trying to go with this.

Comment: @whuber This is a counter-example to the claim that 'given a 1-dimensional minimal sufficient statistic, there can be no 2-dimensional minimal sufficient statistic', or more generally, no d-dimensional minimal sufficient statistic. My $T$ is the counter-example to this claim

Comment: In what sense is $T$ anything other than one-dimensional, apart from the notation you use?  Dimensionality, to be meaningful, must be an *intrinsic* property of a statistic and not subject to change merely through a change of mathematical notation.  In this case, the dimension of the affine subspace of $\mathbb R^d$ generated by all possible values of $T$ is at most $1.$  Generally, one would be concerned with the local dimension of the image of $T$ (which could be curvilinear), but in this example we don't even have to worry about that.

Comment: I agree with that - I am just not sure how best to respond to this claim then.. I appreciate that the question itself is flawed, perhaps it is trying to illustrate the distinction between Euclidean dimension and sufficiency.